# Gradle Android - Override standard tasks

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to customize the behavior of my Gradle build to be Android-Wear friendly.

I am bundling manually my wear apk in my handled apk (because i didnt managed to do it automagically).

This means that if I want to build a new version of the handled apk, i have to manually build my wear apk, copy/past the generated wear-apk insinde my res/raw of the handled project then build the new handled apk.

I want all this to be automatized.

So, what I need to do is :

1. Launch app:assembleRelease from cmd line
2. Gradle first do a wear:assembleRelease
3. At the end, Gradle take the apk from `wear/output/apk/wear-apk.apk` and copy it in `app/src/main/res/raw`
4. Then Gradle can procede to do app:assembleRelease

I dont find how to launch a task (wear:assembleRelease) from another task.

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that may not be optimal but it is working for what I need.

In my handled app, i first have to say that the assembleRelease depends on my wear:assembleRelease:

app/build.gradle

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(':wear:assembleRelease')
}
```

`preReleaseBuild`is one of the very first task of the build but this task is created dynamically, that's why you have to wrap it after the project is evaluated.

Then, in my wear `build.gradle`, I have to specify the copy at the end of the build:

wear/build.gradle

```
assembleRelease << {
    println "Copying the Wear APK"
    copy {
        from 'build/outputs/apk'
        into '../app/src/main/assets'
        include '**/wear-release.apk'
    }
}
```

With only theses modifications, i managed to have the workflow explained in the question.

This could be enhanced because it is only working for the release build but it's a good first step.

Feel free to comment this solution.